# expect: code print out how many time x(you type in) appear in matrix... actual: code print out the amount of value

Tags: c++, matrix

expect: code print out how many time x(you type in) appear in matrix... actual: code print out the amount of value
hey guys, for some of you this question might be idiotic, but i have just started to learn c++ recently so please, sympathetic :(( and i apologize for my bad english

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int NhapMang(int A[100][100], int &n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            {
                cout << "Nhap A[" << i << "][" << j << "]: ";
                cin >> A[i][j];
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
int XuatMang(int A[100][100], int &n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            cout << A[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
int SoLanXuatHien(int A[100][100], int &n, int &x)
{
    int dem=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            if(A[i][j]==x);
            {
                dem++;
            }
        }
    }
    return dem;
}

int main()
{
    int n, A[100][100],x;
    cout << "moi nhap n: ";
    cin >> n;
    NhapMang(A,n);
    XuatMang(A,n);
    cout << "moi nhap x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "\nso lan xuat hien: \n";
    cout << SoLanXuatHien(A,n,x);
    return 0;
}
```

matrix: 
1 2 3
4 5 6 
7 8 9
x: 4

expect: 1
actual: 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is this line

```
if(A[i][j]==x);
```

In C++, even a simple semicolon is treated as a statement. Its actually equivalent to this:

```
if (A[i][j] == x)
    ;
```

In your case, Because you didn't put braces around your statement, your code will be somewhat equivalent to this:

```
....
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if(A[i][j]==x) {

        }

        {
            dem++; // dem will be incremented every time loop iterates. That's why you got 9
        }
    }
}
```

Remove semicolon and everything will work fine.

**Corrected Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int NhapMang(int A[100][100], int &n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            {
                cout << "Nhap A[" << i << "][" << j << "]: ";
                cin >> A[i][j];
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
int XuatMang(int A[100][100], int &n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            cout << A[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
int SoLanXuatHien(int A[100][100], int &n, int &x)
{
    int dem=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            if(A[i][j]==x)
            {
                dem++;
            }
        }
    }
    return dem;
}

int main()
{
    int n, A[100][100],x;
    cout << "moi nhap n: ";
    cin >> n;
    NhapMang(A,n);
    XuatMang(A,n);
    cout << "moi nhap x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "\nso lan xuat hien: \n";
    cout << SoLanXuatHien(A,n,x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: TBH I wouldnt bother pasting OP's 100 lines of code in, it doesn't add anything. Simpy showing the corrected code (and maybe mentioning why it was incorrect) would be fine

Comment: @Tas As per your suggestion, I have added some explanation. Thanks.